# get set descriptors for input.value error

Tags: javascript, frontend

```
var inp = document.querySelector('input');
Object.defineProperty(inp, "value", {
    get: function() {
      console.log('getter');
      return this.value;
    },
    set: function(value) {
       console.log('setter');
       this.value = value + '1';
    }
});
```

I want to write my logic with set input value, but this code not working, infinity loop, when i try get or set value;

How i can do custom handler, on change value? 
(I need change value, in this way: input.value="custom", no input.setValue("custom")! )

Comment: You could simply use `input.addEventListener('change', function(){ /* validate here*/ })`. I would not define setter and getter for this value as the system is using it. You could potentially use a `Proxy`, but thats rather complicated...

Comment: Look at your getter; you're essentially saying, when the code asks for `this.value`, call my getter, which should return `this.value`. That then calls your getter, which tells it to return `this.value`... How could it not go into an infinite loop?

Comment: perhaps you mean to encapsulate a property _value or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('input');

function createGetSetValue( inputElement ){
  var value = inputElement.value;
  Object.defineProperty( inputElement, "value", {
    get: function(){ return value; },
    set: function( v ){ value = v + '1'; }
  });
  return inputElement;
};

createGetSetValue( inp );

inp.value = 10;
console.log( inp.value ) // Logs 101
```

```html
<input value="2" />
```

Because when you use `this.value = x`, you are calling the setter *again* (causing the infinite loop). This will store the value independently and set up the getter and setter to return *that* value instead of the one actually stored in the input, allowing you to modify it without invoking the getter and setter again.